# First-order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I solve this differential equation for $y(x)$?

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-xy}{x-xy}$

$y -\ln(y) = x - \ln(x) + C$

I'm not sure what to do at this point. I looked it up on WolframAlpha and the solution uses something called a Product Log Function. How does it work? And how does the solution come out to be:

$y(x) = -W(-e^{(c_1-x)} x)$

Comment: Looks like the Lambert W function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Are you meant to leave it in that form or do you need to have the reduced expression of the lambert function? Check your answer sheet. As it stands the non lambert version is just as good unless you need a $y =\text{blah}$  form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-xy}{x-xy}=\frac{y(1-x)}{x(1-y)}\implies \frac{(1-y)dy}{y}=\frac{(1-x)dx}{x}\implies \ln y-y=\ln x-x+c \\(-y)e^{(-y)}=-e^cxe^{(-x)}$$
Now if:
$$ae^a=b\iff a=W(b)$$
So:
$$-y=W(-e^cxe^{-x})\implies t=-W(-e^{c-x}x)$$